# "IN" in Crystal Reports

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports-2008

I have used a **report Selection formula** to filter the report. One of the criteria is:

```
{vw_ELog_Jobs.Job No_} IN ['AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD','EEEE']
```

"vw_ELog_Jobs" is a view.

When the array having a smaller count, the report is ok, but when array is having a large count(about 3000 array items), the report gives an error.

AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE is also taken from one of the column in "vw_ELog_Jobs".

I want to achieve this task inside the crystal report. So the array also should dynamically set inside the report.

Comment: What error you are getting and are the array items are from database or those are manually provided?

Comment: "The formula,record filter or group filter is not a valid formula."

Comment: I guess it is a constraint in crystal reports on number of items to be used in an array in record selection. I have tried upto 1000 items it worked but after that If i add one more item it throwed error.

Comment: Linked article from a deleted answer: [Crystal Reports: Avoiding Array Size Limits Using Concatenation \[Field Notes\]](https://seankilleen.com/2012/07/crystal-reports-avoiding-array-size-limits-using-concatenation-field-notes/)